# Promise resolving too early

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm having an issue where my Promise.all is resolving too early. For a test I want to console.log the length of the array which is getting pushed from within the promise map but it is returning 0 sadly. I'm sure it's something simple...

```
fromPath(job.data.path, { density: 100, format: "png" }).bulk(-1, true).then(output => {
  Promise.all(output.map(page => 
    jimp.read(Buffer.from(page.base64, 'base64')).then(img => 
      {
        img.invert().getBase64Async(jimp.AUTO).then(data => imageArray.push(data.replace('data:image/png;base64,', ''))).catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
      ).catch(err => console.log(err))
      )).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
  // This returns early
).then(console.log(imageArray.length)).then(done()).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `then` callback doesn't return anything. You should *return* `Promise.all()`, and you should *return* `img.invert().....`

Comment: **It's a typo.** You've forgotten to return the promise from `img.invert().getBase64Async` in the `.then` handler it's in, so the promise from `.then` doesn't wait for the promise from `getBase64Async`. (Also the Promise.all above, and calling `console.log` directly and passing its return value into `.then`, and...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues there. Mainly they fall into these categories:

- Not returning the results of promise chains from fulfillment handlers, which means the chain the fulfillment handler is in won't be linked up to the promise chain you created within it
- Calling functions and passing their return value into `then`, rather than passing a function into `then`

See inline comments in this *minimal, least-changes* reworking of that code:

```
fromPath(job.data.path, { density: 100, format: "png" }).bulk(-1, true)
.then(output => {
    // Return the result of `Promise.all`
    return Promise.all(
        output.map(
            page => jimp.read(Buffer.from(page.base64, 'base64'))
                .then(img => {
                    // Return the ersult of this promise chain
                    return img.invert().getBase64Async(jimp.AUTO)
                    .then(data => imageArray.push(data.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '')))
                    // This error handler does nothing useful, since we now return
                    // the promise chain
                    // .catch(err => console.log(err))
                })
                // Recommend **not** handling errors at this level, but using
                // `Promise.allSettled` instead
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        )
    )
    // This will only be reached if a *synchronous* error occurs calling (for instance)
    // `getBase64Async`, since you've already caught errors above
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
// Use a function here, don't call `console.log` directly
.then(() => console.log(imageArray.length))
//    ^^^^^^
// Pass `done` directly to `then`, don't call it and pass its return value
// (e.g., remove the `()`)
.then(done) // Or `.then(() => done)` if you want `done` called with no arguments
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

FWIW, though, if I had to not use `async` functions I'd probably do it like this:

```
fromPath(job.data.path, { density: 100, format: "png" }).bulk(-1, true)
.then(output => Promise.allSettled(
    output.map(
        page => jimp.read(Buffer.from(page.base64, 'base64'))
            .then(img => img.invert().getBase64Async(jimp.AUTO))
            .then(data => {
                imageArray.push(data.replace('data:image/png;base64,', ''));
            })
    )
))
.then(results => {
    // Show errors
    const errors = results.filter(({status}) => status === "rejected");
    for (const {reason} of errors) {
        console.error(reason);
    }
    // Done
    done();
});
```

Comment: Hi TJ, thanks so much for your help and verbose commenting! You're a star. RE: inline formatting and reading up on promises, all a work in progress my friend. Thanks again.

Comment: @TobyBoulton - :-) Glad that helped. I've added a second version which may be useful. Happy coding!